La sesión no se mantiene cuando me desplazo por las rutas o me redirijo en mi proyecto en express
cuando creo una sesión en mi proyecto de express, me sucede que cuando me desplazo por las diferentes ruta, esa sesión desaparece.
Entiendo que la configuración en mi index.js es correcto, estoy utilizando express-session es mas, se crea la sesión pero no se mantiene.
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const bodyParse = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session');
const cookies = require('cookie-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const mainRouter = require('./router/mainRouter');
const dashboardRouter = require('./router/dashboardRouter');
const userLoggedMiddleware = require('./middleware/userLoggedmiddelware');

app.use(session({
  secret: "casa_partida",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {secure: true}
}));

app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParse.json());

app.use(cookies());
app.use(userLoggedMiddleware);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.use(expressLayout);
app.set('layout', './layouts/main');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(mainRouter);
app.use(dashboardRouter);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.status(404).render('errornotfound');
})

app.use(helmet())

app.disable('x-powered-by');
module.exports = app;

creo la sesión en req.session.user = profile y le asigno el usuario logueado, ahora cuando me redirijo a la vista dashboard res.redirect('/dashboard') y en ese momento se pierde la sesión creada.
postLogin : async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const profile = await db.users.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email}});
      if(profile){
        if (req.body.password == '') {
          return res.render('login', {errors: { password:{ msg: "El campo de la contraseña no puede estar vacio" }}})
        }
        if(bcryptjs.compareSync(req.body.password, profile.contrasenia)){
          delete profile.contrasenia;
          req.session.user = profile;
          
          if (req.body.saveme) {
            res.cookie('userEmail', req.body.email, {maxAge: (1000 * 60) * 60})
          }
          res.redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
          return res.render('login', { errors: { email: { msg: "Las credenciales son invalidas" }}})
        }
      } else {
        return res.render('login', { errors: { email: { msg: "Este email no se encuetra registrado" }}})
      }
    } catch (e) {
      const locals = {
        title: "Problema en el iniciar de sesión",
        description: "Lo sentimos ha surgido un error"
      }
      res.render('error', { error: "hubo un problema al iniciar sesión contacte al soporte técnico", code: e, locals })
    }
  }

para tratar de mantener este sesión creé el middleware userLoggedmiddleware.js pero aun no pude hacer que la sesión se mantenga.
const db = require("../../../database/models");

 async function userLoggedMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.user){
      res.locals.isLogged = true;
      res.locals.userLogged = req.session.user;
    }else{
    
      res.locals.isLogged = false;

      let emailInCookie = req.cookies.userEmail;
    
      let userFromCookie = await db.users.findOne({
        where: {
          email: emailInCookie || null
        },
      });
    
      if (userFromCookie) {
        req.session.userLogged = userFromCookie;
      }

      if (req.session.userLogged) {
        res.locals.isLogged = true;
        res.locals.userLogged = req.session.userLogged;
      }
  }
  next();
  
}

module.exports = userLoggedMiddleware;

¿Hay algo que esta mal?, ¿Cómo lo solucionaría?, ¿Algo que debería tener en cuenta?

¿Estas trabajando sobre https? No? Proba sacar secure: true. Más info

Por ahora las pruebas las hago en localhost. Probé sacando "secure: true" y sigo sin poder solucionarlo.
